# Sending multiple PHP associative arrays from HTM form to build an array structure

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have the bellow form to send PHP arrays. 
In my form the area commented id duplicated on how many rooms are sekected

The form can be found below:

```
<div class="col-xs-4">
       <label>Camere</label>
       <div class="selector">
          <select id='rooms' class="full-width">
             <option value="1">1</option>
             <option value="2">2</option>
             <option value="3">3</option>
             <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
       </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <!--START-->
    <div id="room-1">
    <h5 class="title">CAMERA 1</h5>
    <div class="row">
       <div class="col-xs-4">
          <label>ADULTS</label>
          <div  class="selector">
             <select id='adults-1' name="adults-1[]" class="full-width">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
             </select>
          </div>
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-4">
          <label>Copii</label>
          <div  class="selector">
             <select id='kids-1'  name="kids-1[]" class="full-width">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                >
             </select>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div class="age-of-children no-display">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4 child-age-field">
             <label>Copil 1</label>
             <div class="selector validation-field">
                <select class="full-width" name="kidsage-1[]"id='kidsage-1'>
                   <option value="0">0</option>
                   <option value="1">1</option>
                   <option value="2">2</option>
                   <option value="3">3</option>
                   <option value="4">4</option>
                   <option value="5">5</option>
                   <option value="6">6</option>
                   <option value="7">7</option>
                </select>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
    <!--END-->
```

What i need to acomplish , ? 
After sending the form on the response page i need to build an array structure based on the information send to the form.
Example:

If i select on the 2 rooms  i will have the below HTML

```
**<!--ROOM 1-->**
<div id="room-1">
<h5 class="title">CAMERA 1</h5>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4">
      <label>ADULTS</label>
      <div  class="selector">
         <select id='adults-1' name="adults-1[]" class="full-width">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4">
      <label>Copii</label>
      <div  class="selector">
         <select id='kids-1'  name="kids-1[]" class="full-width">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            >
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="age-of-children no-display">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 child-age-field">
         <label>Copil 1</label>
         <div class="selector validation-field">
            <select class="full-width" name="kidsage-1[]"id='kidsage-1'>
               <option value="0">0</option>
               <option value="1">1</option>
               ..........................
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

**<!--ROOM 2-->**
<div id="room-2">
<h5 class="title">CAMERA 2</h5>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-4">
      <label>ADULTS</label>
      <div  class="selector">
         <select id='adults-2' name="adults-2[]" class="full-width">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-xs-4">
      <label>Copii</label>
      <div  class="selector">
         <select id='kids-2'  name="kids-2[]" class="full-width">
            <option value="0">0</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            >
         </select>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="age-of-children no-display">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-4 child-age-field">
         <label>Copil 1</label>
         <div class="selector validation-field">
            <select class="full-width" name="kidsage-2[]"id='kidsage-1'>
               <option value="0">0</option>
               <option value="1">1</option>
               ..........................
            </select>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<!--END-->
```

And on the first room i select 1 ADULT
on the second room i select 2 ADULTS and 1 Child who has 1 Year

I need to be outputed as:

```
  // First Room
  $rooms[] = array(array("paxType" => "Adult"));

  // Second Room
  $rooms[] = array(array("paxType" => "Adult"), array("paxType" => "Adult"), array("paxType" => "Child", "age" => 1));
```

I have tried different ways but i can manage only to input adults and child but not their age also. I need the outbut to be as the above because on the API SOAP requirements.